# not showing different charts on single form

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

hi I am trying to represent the two graphs(pie chart and bar chart) on one form using mschart controls....the data is coming from database ....

I am using single chart(kpichart) control to represent the two graphs ....

for that i ahve wrrittent teh below code

In this code i have defined two different areas to defining two graphs.....

```
       public void KpiMembers_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       {

        Series statusseries;
        Series liveserries = null;
        string area;
        Title title;

        try
        {
            var pos = e.Location;
            var results = KpiMembersTotalchart.HitTest(pos.X, pos.Y, false, ChartElementType.DataPoint);
            foreach (var result in results)
            {
                if (result.ChartElementType == ChartElementType.DataPoint)
                {
                    if (result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].AxisLabel == "Live")
                    {
                        DataTable Livemembers = null;
                        Livemembers = KpiData.livemembersmembershipstatus();

                        DataTable membersalltotals = null;
                        membersalltotals = kpimembtotals.membershipTotals(dtpStartDate.Value, dtpenddate.Value);

                        KpiMembersTotalchart.ChartAreas.Clear();
                        KpiMembersTotalchart.Titles.Clear();
                        KpiMembersTotalchart.Series.Clear();


                        area = "newchart";
                        KpiMembersTotalchart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
                        liveserries = KpiMembersTotalchart.Series.Add(area);
                        liveserries.ChartArea = area;

                        title = KpiMembersTotalchart.Titles.Add("Memberstotalspoints");
                        title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
                        title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
                        title.DockedToChartArea = area;


                        KpiMembersTotalchart.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;

                        area = "subchart";
                        KpiMembersTotalchart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
                        statusseries = KpiMembersTotalchart.Series.Add(area);
                        statusseries.ChartArea = area;


                        title = KpiMembersTotalchart.Titles.Add("Live Status members by status");
                        title.Font = new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10, FontStyle.Bold);
                        title.Alignment = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
                        title.DockedToChartArea = area;

                        KpiMembersTotalchart.Titles.Add("").DockedToChartArea = area;



                        foreach (Title chartTitle in KpiMembersTotalchart.Titles)
                        {
                            chartTitle.IsDockedInsideChartArea = false;
                        }

                        foreach (ChartArea chartArea in KpiMembersTotalchart.ChartAreas)
                        {
                            chartArea.Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
                            chartArea.AxisX.LabelStyle.IsEndLabelVisible = true;

                        }

                        if (area == "subchart")
                        {
                            foreach (Series charttypes in KpiMembersTotalchart.Series)
                            {
                                charttypes.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
                                charttypes["PielabelStyle"] = "Outside";
                                charttypes["DoughnutRadius"] = "30";
                                charttypes["PieDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";
                                charttypes.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;

                            }

                        }

                        if (area == "newchart")
                        {
                            foreach (Series chartareas in KpiMembersTotalchart.Series)
                            {
                                chartareas.ChartType = SeriesChartType.StackedColumn;
                                chartareas["ColumnDrawingStyle"] = "SoftEdge";
                                chartareas["LabelStyle"] = "Top";
                                chartareas.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
                                chartareas.BackGradientStyle = GradientStyle.DiagonalLeft;
                            }
                        }


                        foreach (Legend legend in KpiMembersTotalchart.Legends)
                        {
                            legend.Enabled = false;
                        }

                        if (membersalltotals == null)
                        {
                            statusseries.Points.Clear();
                            statusseries.Points.AddXY("no status", 0);

                        }

                        if(Livemembers == null)
                        {

                            liveserries.Points.Clear();
                            liveserries.Points.AddXY("no membershipe", 0);

                        }
                        KpiMembersTotalchart.Series["newchart"].Points.DataBindXY(membersalltotals.Rows, "Status", membersalltotals.Rows, "Value");
                        KpiMembersTotalchart.Series["subchart"].Points.DataBindXY(Livemembers.Rows, "mshipname", Livemembers.Rows, "count");

                        if (area == "subchart")
                        {
                            foreach (Series charttypes in KpiMembersTotalchart.Series)
                            {
                                foreach (DataPoint point in charttypes.Points)
                                {
                                    switch (point.AxisLabel)
                                    {
                                        case "New": point.Color = Color.Cyan; break;
                                        case "Live": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
                                        case "Defaulter": point.Color = Color.Red; break;
                                        case "Cancelled": point.Color = Color.Orange; break;
                                        case "Completed": point.Color = Color.Blue; break;
                                        case "Frozen": point.Color = Color.Violet; break;
                                    }

                                    point.Label = string.Format("{0:0} - {1}", point.YValues[0], point.AxisLabel);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        if (area == "newchart")
                        {
                            foreach (Series chartareas in KpiMembersTotalchart.Series)
                            {
                                foreach (DataPoint point in chartareas.Points)
                                {

                                    switch (point.AxisLabel)
                                    {
                                        case "Silver membership": point.Color = Color.Green; break;
                                        case "Gold Membership": point.Color = Color.Blue; break;
                                        //case "Refused": point.Color = Color.Red; break;
                                        case "Weekend Peak": point.Color = Color.Cyan; break;
                                        case "prspect": point.Color = Color.Indigo; break;

                                    }
                                    point.Label = string.Format("{0:0}", point.YValues[0]);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
        catch { }

    }
```

My problem is i am trying to showing the two different charts (one is pie chart and another one is stacked column chart)....

but it was showing two same charts (both are pie charts)  see the below diagram[image]

I want to show the stacked column chart instead of pie chart in second one....but it was showing two same charts(pie )

i have divided the total form in to two areas .....

What I have to do to show the two different graphs on same form using single chart control

would any one pls help on this....

Many Thanks in advance for any ideas .....

Comment: would any one pls help on this .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple problem with the logic in your code.

Your code currently reads:

```
                    area = "newchart";
                    ......
                    area = "subchart";
                    ......
                    if (area == "subchart")
                    ......
                    if (area == "newchart")
```

This obviously will always evaluate the first "if" to "true" and the second "if" to "false". You need to reorganise your code so that it doesn't use `area` like this - you need to step back and rewrite your logic that creates the charts you need.

Comment: how do you ever expect `area` to equal "newchart" after you've called `area="subchart"`? Try refactoring your code using smaller methods - it will help you see and understand the flow of the code.

Comment: if you want this code to work you have to understand it - read the code and understand it. If you can't understand it because its too long then try to break it down into methods of less than 20 lines each. Each method will have a name that makes sense - and the method names will help you to understand it. Good luck

Comment: how do i write the logic so that two different graphs will be seen on the one form...any idea .....is it possible to use single area to plot two charts....

Comment: yes - it's possible. You need to slow down and read your code. Try stepping through it with a debugger?

Comment: how about if you start by trying to split it into two functions: plotpiechart() and plotstackchart()